# Superluminescent LED

Tags: optics, semiconductor-physics, light-emitting-diodes

How do [Superluminescent LED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superluminescent_diode) generate amplified spontaneous emission?  Moreover," a superluminescent LED combines the spatial coherence of a laser diode and the temporal incoherence of an LED. " Please explain this.

Comment: What specific problems did you find with the explanations in the linked articles (in your referenced article) on [spontaneous emission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_emission) and  different types of [coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(physics)) (para 4)?

Comment: I don't understand how it really benefits the LED or what it does to it, the two characteristics.